# MYSQL Trigger to update different table based on inserted value

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need to update oc_product_attribute with a value obtained from an inserted row in vehicles. How can I get this specific value? (xxxCOLUMN_VALUExxx)

```
CREATE TRIGGER vehicle_attributes AFTER INSERT ON vehicles
   FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
           UPDATE oc_product_attribute SET oc_product_attribute.vehicle_name =
             (SELECT CONCAT(vehicles.make_name, ' ', vehicles.model_name, ' ', 
              vehicles.chassis) FROM vehicles WHERE vehicles.id = xxxCOLUMN_VALUExxx) 
           WHERE oc_product_attribute.id =  xxxCOLUMN_VALUExxx

        END
```

Even simplified below: I still get an error in MYSQL:

```
CREATE TRIGGER vehicle_attributes AFTER INSERT ON vehicles
   FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
       UPDATE oc_product_attribute 
         SET oc_product_attribute.vehicle_name = 
           CONCAT(NEW.make_name,' ',NEW.model_name,' ',NEW.chassis);            
     END;
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7

And Simplified further:

```
CREATE TRIGGER vehicle_attributes AFTER INSERT ON vehicles
  FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
     UPDATE oc_product_attribute 
      SET oc_product_attribute.vehicle_name = 'test' WHERE 1         
   END;
```

I still get the same error - Could it be MYSQL doesn't have triggers enabled?

Comment: please give the defenitions of the two involved tables vehicles and oc_product_attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to update `oc_product_attribute` like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER vehicle_attributes AFTER INSERT ON vehicles
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
       UPDATE oc_product_attribute 
         SET oc_product_attribute.vehicle_name = 
           CONCAT(NEW.make_name,' ',NEW.model_name,' ',NEW.chassis) 
       WHERE oc_product_attribute.id = NEW.id; 
    END
```

Although I am no sure if oc_product_attribute.id is holding the vehicles.id. However, the important poart is that in an `INSERT AFTER TRIGGER` you can access the values of the inserted row by `NEW.columnName`.

N.B. In update triggers you also can access the value before the change with `OLD.columnName`